# Authentication in Remote Connection to JBoss 4.2.3

Tags: authentication, jboss, jmx

I'm trying to connect to a JBoss MBean, but am getting blocked due to authentication failures.

```
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://"+testIP+":"+testPort);
        env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");

        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "admin");

        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(env);
        RMIAdaptor server = (RMIAdaptor) ic.lookup("jmx/invoker/RMIAdaptor");
        // Get the MBeanInfo for the JNDIView MBean
        ObjectName name = new ObjectName("my.service:service=MyBean");
        MBeanInfo info = server.getMBeanInfo(name);
```

Everything seems to behave fine in terms of connection until the last line when I get:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to authenticate principal=null, securityDomain=jmx-console
at org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPProxyFactory.invoke(JRMPProxyFactory.java:179)
:
:
```

The security domain is configured to use JAAS (in the jmx-invoker-service.xml):

```
<interceptor code="org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.AuthenticationInterceptor"
                 securityDomain="java:/jaas/jmx-console"/>
```

And the user is defined in jmx-console-users.properties properly.

It appears to me that the principal is simply not being read properly. Does JBoss use something other than Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL/CREDENTIALS? It appears from [Their Naming Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r5/html/ch3.chapter.html) that they do not, but why is this failing then?

Many Thanks,

-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting you initial context factory like this:

```
env.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.security.jndi.LoginInitialContextFactory");
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. That was the hint I needed. Unfortunately, using that context factory requires some additional configuration files on the client side. In trying to work out what was needed I discovered another context factory plugs right in and seems to behave as desired: `org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory`

Comment: I was going to suggest that one next... :)